# Angular Material Form Validation

Tags: forms, validation, angular5, angular-material2

If the fields of my FormGroup are model-bound, ala [(ngModel)], and become populated on page load, e.g. because of a service, my Submit Button, which is guarded as `[disabled]="biodataForm.status !== 'VALID'"`, does not become disabled. If the form comes up blank and I fill it in normally, the guard passes when the form is correctly filled out. If the same exact values are populated through the data-binding, the biodataForm.status value remains INVALID until I *change* the value of every field.

My feeling is that the form should recognize it has valid content after the data-bindings are populated, and its status should change from INVALID to VALID as a result... what's going wrong here?

My form markup looks like this:

```html
  <form class="form" name="biodataForm" [formGroup]="biodataForm">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="First Name" 
        required
        [(ngModel)]="_memberdata.firstname"
        [formControl]="firstnameFormControl">
      <mat-error *ngIf="firstnameFormControl.invalid">{{getRequiredErrorMessage('firstname')}}</mat-error>        
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" 
        required
        [(ngModel)]="_memberdata.lastname"
        [formControl]="lastnameFormControl">
      <mat-error *ngIf="lastnameFormControl.invalid">{{getRequiredErrorMessage('lastname')}}</mat-error>                
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width"
      hintLabel="Note: We'll send you an email with a link to click to prove it's you">
      <input matInput placeholder="Email" 
        required
        [(value)]="_memberdata.email"
        [formControl]="emailFormControl">
      <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.invalid">{{getEmailErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>        
    </mat-form-field>    
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Phone" type="tel" 
        [(value)]="_memberdata.phone"
        required
        [formControl]="phoneFormControl">
      <mat-error *ngIf="phoneFormControl.invalid">{{getPhoneErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>        
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" 
      class="submit-button"
      [disabled]="biodataForm.status !== 'VALID'"
      (click)="handleNext()">Next Step</button>
  </form>
```

```

My Angular component surrounding this form looks like this (details omitted for clarity, full source is [here](https://github.com/ithacagenerator/IGOnBoard/tree/master/AngularApp/src/app/welcome)):

```ts
export class WelcomeComponent {
  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
  ]);
  firstnameFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  lastnameFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?-?\s?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4})/)
  ]);
  // addressFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  biodataForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    email: this.emailFormControl,
    firstname: this.firstnameFormControl,
    lastname: this.lastnameFormControl,
    phone: this.phoneFormControl
    // address: this.addressFormControl
  });

  getEmailErrorMessage() {
    return this.emailFormControl.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
      this.emailFormControl.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
  }
  getPhoneErrorMessage() {
    return this.phoneFormControl.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
      this.phoneFormControl.hasError('pattern') ? 'Format must be (xxx) xxx-xxxx' : '';
  }
  getRequiredErrorMessage(field) {
    return this.biodataForm.get(field).hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
  }

  constructor(
    public _memberdata: MemberDataService,
    private _api: ApiService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  handleNext() {
     // ... handle button click
  }
}
```

```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form itself can be checked with valid and invalid. The below should work:

```
[disabled]="biodataForm.invalid"
```

Info on the Angular form group can be found at: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

In addition, the email and phone inputs...you are using [(value)]...change those to [(ngModel)] and it should work the way you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately, just tried this, behaves the same way as my posted code (re: not identifying 'valid' state with preloaded model-bound fields). Live development version is running at https://ithacagenerator.org/onboard if you want to have a look

Comment: Edited my answer...that should do it.

Comment: You rock, thanks so much. That was bone-headed, thanks for the fresh eyes.